# requirejs and jquery flexslider

Tags: jquery, requirejs, flexslider

Cant figure out what's wrong with this config.

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "content/themes/wpress/js",

    "paths": {
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery/jquery",
        "flexslider": "vendor/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min",
        "enquire": "vendor/enquire/dist/enquire.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'flexslider': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'flexslider'
        },
        'enquire': {
            exports: 'enquire'
        }
    }
});

    requirejs(['jquery', 'flexslider', 'enquire'],
        function($, flexslider, enquire) {
            // loading flexslider and enquire
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: 'slide',
                slideshow: false,
                itemMargin: 50
            }); //
            console.log(enquire + "Log");
        });
```

With this settings I get "undefined is not a function". How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Give the full actual error message. Right now it is not clear **what specific line of code corresponds to the error**.